Create a boolean array with True for any value between two entries in a certain array
I have a tensor called idx which has integers from 0 to 27, for instance:
idx = torch.tensor([9, 0, 6, 5, 2, 1, 10, 18, 26, 0, 11])

I want to generate another array/tensor which has boolean values. I want the value to be True when it is strictly between 1 (on the left) and 0 (on the right) or the end of the tensor:
flag = torch.tensor([False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False])

Notice that if the 0 does not appear after the 1, I still want True until the end of the tensor. That is,
idx = torch.tensor([9, 0, 6, 5, 2, 1, 10, 18])
flag = torch.tensor([False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True])

Is there a fast way to do this without an expensive for loop? Or if the for-loop is unavoidable, what's the most efficient way to do this?
Importantly, my idx will always have 0 and 1 at regular intervals and they will always alternate. In particular, there are always exactly 3 (in this case) elements between 1 and 0 or between 0 and 1.

Will the first 0 always be before the first 1?

@Dogbert not necessarily. Basically, I have a very long sequence that I have created by putting3 numbers different from 0 and 1, then I put a 1 then I put 3 numbers different from 0 and 1 and then I put a 0 and repeat. This sequence is very long.
I then sample a random starting point of this long sequence, like a little window, which in this case is idx.

Will the number of values between 0 and 1 always be 3 or can it be a different value (but consistent in the same series)?

@Dogbert by construction, the number of values between 0 and 1 will always be 3. However, since I grab a random "window" of the sequence, some of these might be cut-off.

My attempt (if I understood well the question)
r=(idx==1).cumsum()-(idx==1)
r-=((idx==0) & (r!=0)).cumsum()
flags = r.astype(bool) # If needed to have bools instead of 0/1

There are probably other tricks like that (honestly, that is the kind of cumulative problems for which it is often easier to just use numba or C, or etc. I take that if you use torch, it is because you plan to run this on GPU/TPU or some specific hardware, so it is not necessarily easi).
But if the goal is to hijack numpy's internal for loop to avoid writing some ourselves (which is the goal of most of the numpy tagged questions I answer), then, this one is probably as good as any.

The solution breaks down in the second interval, for example [2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2] would result in [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]. Replacing r==1 with r>=1 or r>0 in the second line fixes this.

@simon yes indeed, my bad. Corrected. That was indeed the spirit of second line: remove the number of 0, unless 0. come first (r=0). So r!=0 is the criteria>

You're welcome! It is a pretty elegant solution!

Here's a way to do this using only torch tensor operations based on the constraints in the question:

Find the indexes of all 1s
Create an array of false values of the same length
Set the value of indexes ones + 1, ones + 2, and ones + 3 to True. The indexes need to be clamped to len(x) - 1 prevent out of bounds indexing.

def f(x):
    ones = (x == 1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
    flag = torch.zeros_like(x, dtype=torch.bool)
    flag[torch.clamp(ones + 1, max=len(x) - 1)] = True
    flag[torch.clamp(ones + 2, max=len(x) - 1)] = True
    flag[torch.clamp(ones + 3, max=len(x) - 1)] = True
    return flag


print(f(torch.tensor([9, 0, 6, 5, 2, 1, 10, 18, 26, 0, 11])))
print(f(torch.tensor([9, 0, 6, 5, 2, 1, 10, 18])))
print(f(torch.tensor([1, 10, 18])))

Output:
tensor([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
        False])
tensor([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True])
tensor([False,  True,  True])

